# How do I handle an exception and send back an HTTP response in mulesoft?

Tags: mule

in Mulesoft, how do I take a globally caught exception in a HTTP driven flow and return an error code (rather than it not returning anything back?)  Basically I have an HTTP endpoint (request/response), which then makes a database connection.  If the db connection fails, its caught, but the HTTP response responds with something unrecognizable.  What is the graceful way to force a 500 for example?  Thanks! BY

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, for Mule 3.5 and earlier version, you can configure **HTTP response builder** in the global exception block and return status HTTP code :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/HTTP+Response+Builder 
and 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Response+Builder

For Mule 3.6 you can follow this :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector

Comment: Thanks!  The issue is that when I get a connection exception which takes it out of the flow, is there a way to return it back to at least posting a proper HTTP response?

Comment: I am not sure if you can catch connection exception .. but here you can check and try what it is suggested :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359294/mule-catch-exception-strategy-doesnt-trigger-on-oracle-jdbc-io-error

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to just catch the connect exception and send a meaningful message out of that you my try out similar to below.

Let the below code be part of your choice-exception-strategy:

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" when="exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException)">
   <logger level="INFO" message="Caught Connect Exception" doc:name="Logger"/>
   <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT" xsl-file="ExceptionTransformer">        
      <mulexml:context-property key="MyException" value="#[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException.getMessage()]"/>
   </mulexml:xslt-transformer>        
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Define a XSLT transformer to transform your payload into the XML you want. Pass the exception message as a context parameter and use it in forming XML. Basically you can design your response in this XSLT. Its your choice whether to extract and send the message caught out of exception or not.

ExceptionTransformer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="MyException"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <GenericException>
     <faultcode>CE101</faultcode>
     <faultstring><xsl:value-of select="$MyException" /></faultstring>
    </GenericException>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may also refer "Returning An Error Message" section if you are using mule 3.6 which makes life really simpler. http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Exception+Strategy+Most+Common+Use+Cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch process option, to hold the exception and based on that you can send your custom response back.